# How find only executable files using 'locate'?

Tags: locate

`locate gtags` would find all the files named `gtags`.

What if I only need executables, is there any way to do this?

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4458120/unix-find-search-for-executable-files

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not easily. You can use

```
locate bash | while IFS= read -r line; do [[ -x "$line" ]] && echo $line; done
```

to find all executables where the name contains `bash`. This is faster than using `find` across the whole filesystem because only a few files need to be checked.

---

- `locate bash` does what it always does (lists all matches)
- `|` (pipe) takes the output from the first command (`locate`) and sends it to the second one (the rest of the line)
- the `while ...; do ... done` loop iterates over every line it receives from the pipe (from `locate`)
- `read -r line` reads one line of input and stores it in a variable called `line` (in our case, a path/file name)
- `[[ -x "$line" ]]` tests whether the file in `$line` is executable
- if it is, the `&& echo $line` part prints it on your screen

Comment: Can you explain the parameters in more detail?

Answer (score 6):

The fastest and least expensive solution:

```sh
locate -b '\gtags' | xargs -ri find {} -prune -type f -executable
```

According to the `xargs` man page, the above syntax passes all filenames found by `locate` to a single execution of `find`, which examines only the specified files.

This solution is better than those given previously because:

- Using `find` to search every file on the system beginning with the root directory may be a short command, but it could take a very long time to run.
- Using a shell while-loop to check each filename can be slow, because it checks each file one at a time.

---

Since others have asked for detailed explanations of the parameters given in earlier answers, the details are:

- `locate` (See: [Invoking locate - Finding Files](http://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/manual/html_node/find_html/Invoking-locate.html))

  - `-b`: Match only the base filename of the pathname against the specified patterns, don't consider the names of the directories in the pathname.
  - `\`: Since the backslash is a globbing character, it prevents `locate` from treating the pattern, `gtags`, as though it were `*gtags*`.  I.e., it looks for files that have the exact name "gtags" without other characters before or after.
- `xargs` (See: [xargs options - Finding Files](https://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/manual/html_node/find_html/xargs-options.html))

  - `-r`: If the standard input is completely empty, do not run the command.
  - `-i`: Substitute `{}` in the following command with the list of filenames read from standard input.
- `find` (See: [find Primary Index - Finding Files](https://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/manual/html_node/find_html/Primary-Index.html))

  - `{}`: `xargs` substitutes this with the names of all the files it receives from `locate` on standard input.  `find` searches all of those files for matches to the following expressions and if any of them are directories, it examines the contents of them, too.
  - `-prune`: If a filename being evaluated belongs to a directory, don't search its contents.
  - `-type f`: Include in the output only filenames that belong to "regular" files, not special ones like devices, named pipes, etc.
  - `-executable`: Include in the output only filenames of executable files.  That is, those with one or more of their executable mode bits set, regardless of the file content.

In short, `locate` prints the names of matching files to standard output, which is piped (using `|`) into the standard input of `xargs`. `xargs` reads the filenames from standard input and combines them into a space-delimited list in a single string.  If the string is not empty, `xargs` substitutes the string for `{}` in the `find` command before executing it.

Comment: I would not exclude executable symlinks matching the filename and add `-L` just before the `{}` argument to the find. That's how you would be able to find e.g. `gcc`.

Answer (score 2):

short answer, use GNU find:

```
find / -type f -executable -name '*gtags*'
```